# Unable to 'forward ' the flutter animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have this code which uses an **AnimationController** and **Tween** to rotate a container along Z-axis when **Start/Stop Button** is pressed. The problem is it forwards the animation only first time after that no matter how many times I press the button it does nothing and the container remains stationary .

**curvesanimation.dart** which has all the animation logic

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;


class CurvedAnimationExample extends StatefulWidget {
  CurvedAnimationExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  CurvedAnimationExampleState createState() => CurvedAnimationExampleState();
}

class CurvedAnimationExampleState extends State<CurvedAnimationExample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 5))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });

    final Animation curve =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn);

    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: math.pi * 2).animate(curve);
  }

  void startStopAnimation() {                      
    print(_animationController.isAnimating.toString());
    if (_animationController.isAnimating)
      _animationController.stop();
    else {
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Transform(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateZ(_animation.value),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: const Text("Start/Stop Animation"),
          elevation: 15,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          onPressed: () => startStopAnimation(),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    print("Curved Animation Example : dispose is called");
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**main.dart** file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'curvesanimations.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomeScaffold(
        title: "Curved Animation Example",
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomeScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomeScaffold({this.title});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: CurvedAnimationExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You want the container to keep on rotating? or rotate back and forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your animation has already reached its endpoint. You can't keep going forward once the end point is reached. An easy fix is to check if the animation is at the endpoint already and reset it to the beginning if it is:

```dart
void startStopAnimation() {                      
    print(_animationController.isAnimating.toString());
    if (_animationController.isAnimating)
      _animationController.stop();
    else {
      print("forward");
      if(_animationController.isCompleted) {//Check if animation is at endpoint
        _animationController.value = 0;
      }
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }
```